# Why I can't pass an argument of type 'char* const *' to a function which expected 'const char* const*' as it's argument?

Tags: c

I am writing a function using fork and execv to replace *system()* and *popen()* in a project.
I found that although execv won't change the content of the command array, it declare it's second argument as **char * const argv[]**, which can actually change the content of char*. Thus I decide to declare my function like this:`int execute_cmd(const char* const cmd[])` so that both the pointer to char is const and the content the const pointer point to is const(Sorry I know this state is confusing but I tried)
However, when I call it in this way:

```
void execute_cmd(const char* const cmd[])
{
    for (int i = 0; cmd[i]; i++)
    {
        printf("%s ", cmd[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char* const cmd[] = {"ls", "-al", 0};
    execute_cmd(cmd);
    return 0;
}
```

there is a complie error saying that:

> test.c:21: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘execute_cmd’ from
> incompatible pointer type
>
> test.c:10: note: expected ‘const char * const*’ but argument is of
> type ‘char * const*’

I wonder why this happen because IMO an formal argument with const can take an non-const variable as it's actual parameter, such as:

```
void printInt(const int);
//which can call like this
int a=10;
printInt(a);
```

And I think initialize a const variable with a non-const variable is very common, So why this function work but my execute_cmd() didn't? Did I miss something importent with the **const**?
I have search "char * const * and const char* const *" and "const formal argument with non-const actual parameter" such things but haven't get something very useful, I will also appreciate if anyone can give me an idea about the correct key-work to this question.
I am not a native English speaker so if there are some grammar problem please forgive me.

Comment: Try `char * const cmd[] = {"ls", "-al", 0};`

Comment: "which can actually change the content of char*" --> Code should not attempt to change `"ls"`, etc.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, it was `char * const cmd[]`, I wrote it wrong

Comment: You are confusing top-level `const` such as `const int`, with the `const` on the pointed-to object such as `char const*`. Location relative to pointer asterisk is of fundamental importance. It's correct that you can't just pass a pointer that says it won't modify the pointed-to object, to a function that declares itself as taking a pointer that might. The rest is just a question of how to work around bad `const`-correctness of APIs or C itself.

Comment: In an other sense, if I try to call it in C++ code, and part of the cmd or arguments are strings, when initialize like `char* const cmd[] = {ls_string.c_str(), al_string.c_str(), 0}` won't work because c_str() return a const char*

Comment: @underscore_d thanks, but "It's correct that you can't just pass a pointer that says it won't modify the pointed-to object, to a function that declares itself as taking a pointer that might" seems just opposite to my situation, I'm trying to pass a array of mutable strings to a function that declares itself will not modify the string.

Comment: I always found this unintuitive as well, but there's a problem case this is meant to prevent.  You can find some info [here](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html).

Comment: "expected 'const char * const *' but argument is of type 'char const'." is inconsistent with code `char * const cmd` and `char * const cmd[]`.  Post true code and true error message.  Avoid typos, use cut/paste.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks, When I do search I have found the answer your mentioned, and saw the example, but my question is slightly different with that one: the difference between `char **` and `char * const *` will make step4 in the example illegle to change a const pointer.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica have post the minimize code can cause the problem. and true gcc's message

Comment: @Eric The case you mentioned in your comment is not the same as the case that's giving you an error. If you have `char **x;` and `char *const *y;`, then you can assign `x` to `y` with no error or warning. The problem is the `const` at the deeper level. There are multiple `const` in your post, but only one at the deeper level is causing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder why this happen because IMO an formal argument with `const` can take an non-const variable as it's actual parameter

It is more like "a formal parameter with `const` can take an non-`const` variable as it's actual  argument."

[`const char* const cmd_paramter[]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=const+char*+const+cmd_paramter%5B%5D) is like an "array of const pointer to const char".

[`char* const cmd_argument[]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char*+const+cmd_argument%5B%5D) is an "array of const pointer to char".

Notice the type of the array elements differ: `const char *` vs. `char *`.

Same problem with simpler code: "expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'const char *'"

```
void foo(char *bob);
const char *alice = "Alice";

// Bad, as `foo()` needs to be able to write `*bob`, yet alice point to `const` data.
foo(alice);
```

---

Further, `cmd` array elements should be of type `const char *` to prevent writing a *string literal*.

```
    // char* const cmd[] = {"ls", "-al", 0};
    const char* const cmd[] = {"ls", "-al", 0};
```

Comment: The "same problem with simpler code" code sample is off-topic. OP is clearly aware one cannot assign const to non-const; the question is about the opposite direction. I think the second part of your answer is the best advice so far: if possible, make everything const.